# Debezium MsSQL source connector exceptions

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using Debezium CDC SQL Server source connector, after a while multiple connectors are failing with either one of the below 2 errors

1. Insufficient argument exception, if I restart the task it will throw the Null pointer exception

```
id: 0,
state: "FAILED",
worker_id: "XXXXXXX:8083",
trace: "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:42)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:268)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:108)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ ... .
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$FetchBuffer.nextRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:5427)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.fetchBufferNext(SQLServerResultSet.java:1758)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:1016)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.source.spi.ChangeTableResultSet.next(ChangeTableResultSet.java:54)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$execute$1(SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:171)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareQuery(JdbcConnection.java:524)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnection.getChangesForTables(SqlServerConnection.java:190)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:162)
    ... 6 more
"
```

2. Null pointer exception

```
id: 0,
state: "FAILED",
worker_id: "XXXXXXX:8083",
trace: "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:42)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:268)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:108)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.debezium.connector.AbstractSourceInfoStructMaker.commonStruct(AbstractSourceInfoStructMaker.java:53)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSourceInfoStructMaker.struct(SqlServerSourceInfoStructMaker.java:37)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSourceInfoStructMaker.struct(SqlServerSourceInfoStructMaker.java:14)
    at io.debezium.connector.AbstractSourceInfo.struct(AbstractSourceInfo.java:76)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerOffsetContext.getSourceInfo(SqlServerOffsetContext.java:91)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerSchemaChangeEventEmitter.emitSchemaChangeEvent(SqlServerSchemaChangeEventEmitter.java:42)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.EventDispatcher.dispatchSchemaChangeEvent(EventDispatcher.java:263)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.migrateTable(SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:276)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$execute$1(SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:221)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareQuery(JdbcConnection.java:524)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnection.getChangesForTables(SqlServerConnection.java:190)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:162)
    ... 6 more
"
```

any insight on these errors / how to resolve them is highly appreciated